# Programmatically switch package in `::` call in R

Tags: r, package

Given a call to a function `bar::foo()`, I would like to be able to programmatically switch the package `bar` so that the same syntax calls `hello::foo()`.

**An example**:

- Let's say I have three packages, `parentPkg`, `childPkg1` and `childPkg2`.
- In `parentPkg` I have a call to function `childPkg1::foo()`
- `foo()` is also a function in `childPkg2`
- I would like to be able, in `parentPkg` to use the `::` operator to call `foo()` but to programatically switch the package name.
  Something like:

  ```
  dummy_pkg_name = ifelse(scenario=="child1", "childPkg1", "childPkg2")
  dummy_pkg_name::foo()
  ```

Is it possible? How do I achieve it?

**Some context**

`parentPkg` is a function that interacts with a web application, takes some request and data and returns results from different statistical models depending on the scenarios.
Each scenario is quite complex and not everything can be generalised in `parentPkg`. For this reason,  `childPkg1` and `childPkg2` (actually there are also 3 and 4) are sort of sub-packages that deals with the data cleaning and various alternatives for each scenario but return the same class of value.
The idea is that `parentPkg` would switch the package to the pertinent child depending on the scenario and call all of the necessary functions without having to write the same sequence for each child but just with a slightly different `::` call.

Comment: I think if(requireNamespace('childPkg1')) is what you really want

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since `::` can be seen as a function, it looks like

```
`::`(dummy_pkg_name, foo)()
```

is what you want. Alternatively,

```
getFromNamespace("foo", ns = dummy_pkg_name)()
```

---

For instance,

```
`::`(stats, t.test)
# function (x, ...) 
# UseMethod("t.test")
# <bytecode: 0x102fd4b00>
# <environment: namespace:stats>

getFromNamespace("t.test", ns = "stats")
# function (x, ...) 
# UseMethod("t.test")
# <bytecode: 0x102fd4b00>
# <environment: namespace:stats>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also create a `call()` that could then be evaluated.

```
call("::", quote(bar), quote(foo()))
# bar::foo()
```

Put into use:

```
c <- call("::", quote(stats), quote(t.test))
eval(c)
# function (x, ...) 
# UseMethod("t.test")
# <bytecode: 0x4340988>
# <environment: namespace:stats>
```

Wrapped up in a function using `setdiff` as our default function:

```
f <- function(pkg, fn = setdiff) {
    pkg <- substitute(pkg)
    fn <- substitute(fn)
    eval(call("::", pkg, fn))
}

f(base)
# function (x, y) 
# {
#     x <- as.vector(x)
#     y <- as.vector(y)
#     unique(if (length(x) || length(y)) 
#         x[match(x, y, 0L) == 0L]
#     else x)
# }
# <bytecode: 0x30f1ea8>
# <environment: namespace:base>

f(dplyr)
# function (x, y, ...) 
# UseMethod("setdiff")
# <environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

Answer (score 2):

To adhere to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), simply re-assign to new named functions in global environment. Be sure to leave out `()` since you are not requesting to run the function.

```
parent_foo <- parentPkg::foo
child1_foo <- childPkg1::foo
child2_foo <- childPkg2::foo
child3_foo <- childPkg3::foo
```

Then, conditionally apply them as needed:

```
if (scenario=="child1") {
  obj <- child1_foo(...)
} 
else if (scenario=="child2") {
  obj <- child2_foo(...)
} 
...
```